# How to download Excel file from website using C# desktop application

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I tried to use few method to download 1 excel file from website

- I tried to use WebClient and DownloadFile... but it return 400 bad
  request
- I tried to use File.WriteAllBytes also kick in exception

My current workaround is call IExplorer with that particular file path ..then it will start to download(after user select file path)

Is that any way that i can straight download excel file without any notification?

Sample Excel Link: https://example.com/sr/XXX.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-all-fields/12345/SearchRequest-12345.xls?tempMax=1000

Comment: Please provide some code, with explanation of what's not working in the code

Comment: code with actual file link....because sometime what happens that simple link is different then actual download link..(for example redirecting...etc etc)